# Fastly CNAME to api subdomain on Heroku (with SSL)

Tags: heroku, dns, cdn, cname

I'm trying to set up Fastly's API acceleration which requires setting up a CNAME for my api subdomain to `global.prod.fastly.net`.

But I already have a CNAME pointing to my Heroku subdomain, for example `unagi-xxxx.herokussl.com`.

I can't set the domain in Fastly itself to `unagi-xxxx.herokussl.com` as this endpoint is not accessible directly, but through a custom domain only.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

In your DNS provider's website, set up a CNAME record to point to 'global.prod.fastly.net'.

Then, in your Heroku environment, remove your custom domain, eg:

```
$ heroku domains:remove api.blah.com
```

This will force all api.blah.com traffic through fastly, which will then query your Heroku app behind the scenes (transparently).

Also note: even if you do NOT remove the custom subdomain from Heroku, things will still work. Heroku won't ever blacklist your built-in Heroku DNS name.